# SOLVED: How can I open a User Control WinForm with a dropdown button click from a WinForm in devexpress C# project?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a winform named "QuickMenu". This QuickMenu form contains collapse and expands buttons. Please check the attachment screenshot.

[image: Expand And Collapse Form]

I want to open a User Control WinForm by clicking the button on the "QuickMenu" form. I have written the following code in QuickMenu.cs:

```
Public partial class QuickMenu : Form
{
   private CollectionReport collection;
}

public QuickMenu()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   collection = new CollectionReport();
}

private void resCollection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   collection.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   this.Controls.Add(collection);
   timer1.Start();
}
```

Note: This code is written for the "Collection" button.
After writing this code, the output is the following screenshot.

[image]

How can I show the User Control in full screen?
The User Control is supposed to look like:

[image]

Note: Orders, Collection, Delivery and Setup buttons are in another form named "AllSettingsForm". And also, this button has a separate form that is called into the AllSettingsForm. Look at the solution, and I hope you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Are you using scaffolding for creating controllers?

Comment: Have you registered your `DbContext` in `startup.cs` file? Have a read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) it'll give you a good understanding

Comment: did you try this : public dataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")

Comment: @Matt Yes, I am using scaffolding for creating controllers.

Comment: this link may be help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

Replace your default constructor by below code

```
public dataContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
{

}
```

If you are using .NET Core then try this:

```
public dataContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions): base(dbContextOptions)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code for the resCollection_Click button. This is the solution I found and the following code works for me.

```
private void resCollection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            collection.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            AllSettingsForm allSettings = new AllSettingsForm();
            allSettings.Controls.Add(collection);
            this.collection.Visible = true;
            this.collection.BringToFront();
            allSettings.Show();
            timer1.Start();
        }
```